# MariaDB and XtraDB/InnoDB plugins

Tags: mysql, innodb, configuration, mariadb, xtradb

In my vps, I thought of switching from MySQL to MariaDB (using Monty's repository for Debian Squeeze). Copying over my.cnf from MySQL to MariaDB, I saw that the new config file (the one from the MariaDB package) does not mention any plugins commands like the old one from MySQL, where I loaded the InnoDB plugin. Now, I understand that XtraDB has become the default ACID storage engine in MariaDB, in place of InnoDB. Since I find MariaDB site's documentation lacking in this area, do I need to put something extra in the new my.cnf to activate XtraDB or is it active by default? `show plugins` returns this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show plugins;
+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+
| Name                           | Status | Type               | Library | License |
+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+
| binlog                         | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysql_native_password          | ACTIVE | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysql_old_password             | ACTIVE | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| MyISAM                         | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| partition                      | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| ARCHIVE                        | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| BLACKHOLE                      | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| CSV                            | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| FEDERATED                      | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| MEMORY                         | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| Aria                           | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| MRG_MYISAM                     | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| PBXT                           | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| PBXT_STATISTICS                | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| InnoDB                         | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_RSEG                    | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES       | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_INDEX | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_BLOB  | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TRX                     | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_LOCKS                   | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_LOCK_WAITS              | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP                     | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET               | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                  | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET            | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLE_STATS             | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_INDEX_STATS             | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| XTRADB_ADMIN_COMMAND           | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLES              | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_SYS_INDEXES             | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_SYS_STATS               | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| XTRADB_ENHANCEMENTS            | ACTIVE | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+
33 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What do I understand from the output above? That InnoDB=XtraDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown from your `SHOW PLUGINS;`, InnoDB is present. XtraDB is also present.

If you want to be sure, you must run `SHOW ENGINES;`. That will show what storage engine is the default. The fact that the XtraDB plugins are active shows that XtraDB must be in use.

Comment: You're right. I've just issued the command and it shows: `| InnoDB     | DEFAULT | XtraDB engine based on InnoDB plugin. Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |`